# Icons/emojis not rendering in browser and displaying symbols when displaying page in browser while running from WebStorm IDE

Tags: html, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am developing a HTML page. I have a **book icon** in the page under `<h1>` tag. File name is **index.html**. When I run the page directly by double clicking it... it displays the book icon on the browser. When I run the page by clicking Firefox icon from inside **WebStorm IDE**... it displays some symbols instead of book icon.

Is it because of WebStorm or did I miss anything in HTML??

Below are the screenshots:

###### WebStorm IDE screenshot with book icon

[image]

###### Output displayed on the browser

[image]

I tried to solve this by going through the JetBrains documentation. Couldn't find a solution.

My expected result is... the icons which are placed in the HTML file should be displayed properly in browser when running it from WebStorm IDE.

Comment: Could be file encoding issue (e.g. missing BOM header bytes in a file) .. or the same from the WebStorm's built-in simple web server (not specifying the right encoding). Or perhaps it's a conflict with what is present in a file itself. can you share the file with the blue book icon in it (the actual icon, not the code)? Upload to some file sharing service (Dropbox/Google Drive/OneDrive etc) and share the link -- need the file with no modifications that can be omitted with text copy-paste.

Comment: Also check your encoding settings in the meta tags and/or in CSS. Please refer to the [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_emojis.asp) guide as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the above-mentioned problem given below is the answer.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>The Basic Language of the web: HTML</title>
</head>
```

I added the `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` inside the head tag to mention the character set and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

By directly using the html-code for the blue book emoji, we can achieve this effect:

```
<h1>&#128216; The Code Magazine</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Riley. &#128216; what is the technical name of this code? Like Unicode or something else ?? and where can I find codes like these for emojis and icons?

Comment: Hi, happy to help. The unicode is U+1F4D8, with a name of "Blue Book" A great resource to use is [unicode-table.com](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F4D8/)

Comment: I got it. @Riley you have given me the DECIMAL code for that icon. I did a search and found a page with icons. It has hexadecimal code and decimal code for each icon/emoji.

https://www.quackit.com/character_sets/emoji/emoji_v3.0/unicode_emoji_v3.0_characters_all.cfm

Comment: I did upvote. But I don't have enough reputation. So it wasn't recorded.